# 'windiff' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-vista, batch

I've heard of the `windiff` command, which basically helps us compare 2 files and show the differences.

However, when trying to run it, I get the error

> 'windiff' is not recognized as an intenral or external command, operable program or batch file

Does anyone know why Vista doesn't have a `windiff` function and what are the solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WinDiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff) is not a command-line tool, it is a windowed program (though it does take command-line arguments).

[image]

Furthermore, it is part of Visual Studio, not Windows. However, you can also get it in the [Windows XP Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18546).

It’s pretty [easy to use](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159214), but you can get more out of it by setting the options correctly (eg: uncheck the `Ignore Blanks` option and set the editor, preferably one with a jump-to-line command-line argument).

In addition, there is [a good front-end](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/runwindiff.aspx) for it as well as [a shell-extension](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/wdcmx.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Windiff is a not a part of a standard Windows installation.  The MS Version used to come with Visual Studio.  I dont know if it still does.  However, you can always download Visual Studio Exrpess to see if its there.  Or there are tons of free diff programs on the internet.